# Very high CPU load from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, nginx

LEMP stack on DigitalOcean (48GB ram, 960GB SSD, 12 vCPU) with WordPress on it. Added a new theme and mysql went through the roof. 100% CPU usage, WordPress dashboard becomes inaccessible.

I went through the slow-log and found this query all over:

```
SELECT  t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('post_tag') ORDER BY t.name DESC LIMIT 10;
```

My blog has 91,000 tags. What's causing it? Is there any issue with my mysql settings? Or this query is the culprit? How to solve it?

Comment: Run EXPLAIN of your query, amd show also all indexes of the involved tables.

Comment: I have reverted to the old theme now. Will running explain now give me an explanation?

Comment: not with the s theme, it will only show the execution pkan for your slow quiery, there you can check if all the correct indexes where used or maybe you need a new one, but that we can only messure if you oist your existing indexes. your theme you have to debug, what actually uses that much cpu time

Comment: Do you still have slow queries causing High Cpu Load with the old OR new theme? If you do and you want one of them analyzed, we will need A) query from your slow query log, B) SHOW CREATE TABLE each_table_referenced; and C) SHOW INDEX FROM each_table_referenced; and D) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (your slow query); for analysis.